# How to make aliases with yaml library in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, yaml

I'm using YAML for configuration files and already have all required ToJSON/FromJSON instances for my data types. All good, except there're a lot of repetitive fields, so I'd like to automatically make aliases for them (and replacing all further occurrences of them with aliases) during export.

Instead of

```
- security:
    security_level: authNoPriv
    auth_password: ! 'mypassword'
    username: myuser
    auth_protocol: MD5
    private_protocol: None
    private_password: None
- security:
    security_level: authNoPriv
    auth_password: ! 'mypassword'
    username: myuser
    auth_protocol: MD5
    private_protocol: None
    private_password: None
  ...
```

I'd like to get

```
- security: &securityAlias1
    security_level: authNoPriv
    auth_password: ! 'mypassword'
    username: myuser
    auth_protocol: MD5
    private_protocol: None
    private_password: None
- security: *securityAlias1
  ...
```

How to achieve this in Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current `yaml` version only understands aliases during parsing. It doesn't safe them in its [`Value`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.15.2/docs/Data-Yaml.html#t:Value), since it uses `Data.Aeson.Value` to store YAML values.

Per [`yaml-0.8.15.2`'s description:](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.15.2/docs/Data-Yaml.html)

> For the most part, YAML content translates directly into JSON, and therefore there is very little data loss. ***If you need to deal with YAML more directly (e.g., directly deal with aliases), you should use the [Text.Libyaml](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml-0.8.15.2/docs/Text-Libyaml.html) module instead.*** [emphasis mine]

This means that you have to use the `Text.Libyaml.Event` interface and walk through the events yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I've read this already, but hoped there's some solution for the problem. Guess not. Hope Michael would eventually work on YamlBuilder and YamlParser. JSON is just a subset of YAML spec, but unfortunately, yaml package is built on top of Aeson.

Comment: @AntonK: To be honest, I doubt that a future version of `yaml` won't depend on `aeson` and its `Value` type. You could [add an issue](https://github.com/snoyberg/yaml/issues) to ask for an enhancement, but since this will break most of the existing code, I don't think that this will be implemented. :/

Comment: Of course it won't (and shouldn't, really). I'm talking about improvements to YamlBuilder and Parser that would support full Yaml spec, not just JSON subset. Parser does support that, AFAIK, but not builder.